# nhibernate L2 caching: configure by code

Tags: nhibernate, syscache2, syscache

how to configure second level cache in code (not thru xml)

the current settings i have are:

```
 public NHCachingSetup(Configuration cfg)
        {
            // use first level cache
            cfg.Cache(x =>
            {
                x.UseQueryCache = true;
                x.Provider<SysCacheProvider>();
            });

            // set 60 min expiration time
            cfg.SessionFactory().Caching
                .WithDefaultExpiration(60);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have done this with NH 3.3 is like

```
var configure = new Configuration();
...
configure.Cache(x => x.UseQueryCache = true)
...
configure.SessionFactory().Caching
  .Through<SysCacheProvider>().WithDefaultExpiration(1440);//secs!
```

**edit** in your mapping you will need:-

```
Cache(x => x.Usage(CacheUsage.ReadOnly));
```

**end edit**

Then to use you can do something like (this caches a lookup table for me):-

```
Db.Query<SpamAssassin>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
```

Comment: but there in no L2 cache configuration... i m not able to enable L2 cache in the first place...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. You enable it from the code I  have provided.

Comment: .SetProperty(Environment.UseSecondLevelCache, "true"), is what was missing

Comment: You can also do it the way I have shown, your way is the old way of setting it.

Answer (score 0):

got it:

```
cfg.SetProperty(Environment.BatchSize, "100")
                .SetProperty(Environment.UseQueryCache, "true")
                .SetProperty(Environment.UseSecondLevelCache, "true")
                .Cache(x => { x.Provider<SysCacheProvider>(); });
```

Comment: What version of nh are you using?

Comment: @rippo nh version 3.3.3.. the latest one